# How to install Minikube on Azure Linux VM - ubuntu 18.04

Tags: azure, kubernetes, minikube

I want to install Minikube on Azure Linux VM - ubuntu 18.04. But couldn't find the appropriate article. So I would like to the appropriate steps, how to install Minikube on Azure Linux VM and work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pré-Requisites before create your VM on Azure:
It’s necessary a machine with nested virtualization. The CPU family with suffix _v3 gives this support, ex: Standard D2s v3, Standard D4s v3.
Standard D2s v3 is a good choice to start
I am using: Linux (ubuntu 18.04)

Login to VM using putty:

Installing Docker

```
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

Installing VirtualBox

```
$ sudo apt install virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack
```

Installing Minikube
Updating the system:

```
$ sudo apt update -y
$ sudo apt upgrade -y
```

To install the latest minikube stable release on x86–64 Linux using binary download:

```
$ sudo apt install -y curl wget apt-transport-https


$ curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
 
$ sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

Installing Kubectl

```
$ curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"

$ sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

$ kubectl version --client
```

Start Minikube

```
$ minikube start
```

Check Status

```
$ minikube status

minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured
```

Get Nodes

```
$ kubectl get nodes

NAME       STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
minikube   Ready    control-plane   64s   v1.25.0
```

Addons
Only a few addons are enabled by default during the installation but you can turn on

```
$ minikube addons list
---To activate, run:
$ minikube addons enable <addon-name>
```

Running the First Deployment

```
$ kubectl create deployment my-nginx --image=nginx

$ kubectl get deployments.apps my-nginx

$ kubectl get pods
```