# minikube installation in azure ubuntu vm with docker

Tags: azure, docker, ubuntu, minikube, docker-daemon

I took a ubuntu virtual device in azure and connected through ssh. Installed docker and enabled. I can see docker status as "Active". I installed minikube with all prereqs. However when I try to start minikube with "minikube start" command, am getting below error.

<sup>minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes cluster...
E1006 13:00:41.181623   64011 start.go:83] Error starting host: Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address. Retrying.
E1006 13:00:41.197802   64011 start.go:83] Error starting host: Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address. Retrying.
E1006 13:00:41.213819   64011 start.go:83] Error starting host: Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address. Retrying.
E1006 13:00:41.213960   64011 start.go:89] Error starting host:  Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address
Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address
Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address</sup>

I tried to start minikube deployment and however it failed to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install minikube using docker, create an ubuntu VM. Here I am creating an Ubuntu VM
[image: https://i.imgur.com/AC9rZDE.png]

Once VM is ready, using the public IP of the VM, login to the VM using SSH. Once you've logged in, just as a basic step update your machine using
[image: https://i.imgur.com/hfQYoH1.png]

Install virtual box
[image: https://i.imgur.com/J3ARCls.png]

install docker
[image: https://i.imgur.com/lXzBGsg.png]

restart the docker daemon and install the latest minikube stable release

```
$ sudo apt install -y curl wget apt-transport-https
$ curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
$ sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/bh46X8Q.png]
Once installed, provide the necessary permission. Install kubectl

```
$ curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"

$ sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

and check the Minikube and kubernetes version as below

```
$ kubectl version --client
$ minikube start
$ minikube status
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/BepnCKj.png]

Reference document-
[Installing Minikube doc1](https://www.hackerxone.com/2022/06/08/steps-to-install-configure-minikube-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/#:%7E:text=1%20Step%201:%20Update%20the%20System.%20apt-get%20update,interface%20using%20Public%20Ip%20address.%20...%20More%20items)
[Install Minikube by Gautam Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73895135/how-to-install-minikube-on-azure-linux-vm-ubuntu-18-04)